# Prevent enum parameter from accepting numeric value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The following code produces no warnings:

```
export enum UnitKindEnum {
  UNIT1,
  UNIT2,
}

function func(p: UnitKindEnum) {
    console.log(p);
}

func(UnitKindEnum.UNIT1)
func(-10)
```

How do I force the function to accept only enum types?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is using string enums:

```
export enum UnitKindEnum {
  UNIT1 = "1",
  UNIT2 = "2",
}

function func(p: UnitKindEnum) {
    console.log(p);
}

func(UnitKindEnum.UNIT1)
func("1")
```

That feels a bit like a hack, however.